# Twitter Embedded Timeline widget doesn't load tweet sometimes

Tags: html, twitter

I use twitter embedded timeline widget in my website. I simply copied the HTML from widget generator and pasted it in my site. Most of the time it works. But sometimes it doesn't display any tweets and just displays "Tweets by @xxxxx" text.

I am not sure where the problem is. It's hard to pinpoint as it occurs sometimes only.
Any solution would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. As explained in a Twitter community [forum](https://twittercommunity.com/t/widget-doesnt-load-after-navigating-within-the-website/60991), adding a call to `twitter.widgets.load()` at the end of the widget solved it for me.